# VBA to shift inventory rows up when items are deleted?

Tags: excel, vba

Last summer, I made a pretty basic VBA for an inventory sheet. Column A lists item name, and column B, C, and D are additional info for each item listed. The inventory is two-columned (A2:D28 and G2:J28). The VBA I made makes it so that if I delete the item entry in cell A4, the info in cells B4:D4 clears automatically with it.

The question is: I've been struggling to find a way to make the cells shift up a row when the row above it is cleared, to prevent the list from accumulating empty rows as inventory items are deleted. Most examples I found online were to *delete* those empty cells, whereas I'd rather just clear them and keep my formatting intact.

Is there a way to shift specific cells up like that? And, it would be lovely if there was a way to shift items from the top of the second table (G2:J2) down and over to the bottom of the first table, into A28:D28.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or even a thumb towards a relevant tutorial. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots/code examples to demonstrate what exactly would you like to achieve? Thanks~!

Comment: What do you mean with _The inventory is **two-columned** (A2:D28 and G2:J28)_ ?

Answer (score 0):

This code is a little tricky because of the two columns you have on your screen. My code below reads the two columns into a single one, sorts blank rows to the bottom and then splits the resulting single column back into two. All of this is done without touching the cells themselves. Therefore formatting stays in place.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nsp                        ' Table specs
    ' 023
    ' These enumerations define your table. Modify to suit
    NspAnchorClm = 1            ' 1 = column A
    NspTblClmCount = 4          ' number of Table Columns
    NpsSpaceClmCount = 2        ' number of blank sheet columns between List Columns
    NspListClmCount = 2         ' number of List Columns
    NspFirstRow = 2
    NspNumRows = 10             ' number of rows per List Column
End Enum


Sub ResetList()
    ' 023

    Dim Clm()       As Variant          ' First sheet column of each list column
    Dim ArrIn       As Variant          ' Input data array
    Dim Cin         As Long             ' input column counter
    Dim Rin         As Long             ' input row counter
    Dim ArrOut      As Variant          ' Output data array
    Dim Rout        As Long             ' output row counter
    Dim Rng         As Range            ' the sheet range of varying dimension
    Dim Tmp         As Variant          ' intermediate memory
    Dim L           As Integer          ' List column counter
    Dim C           As Long             ' column counter
    Dim R           As Long             ' row counter

    Clm = Array(NspAnchorClm, NspAnchorClm + NspTblClmCount + NpsSpaceClmCount)
    Tmp = (NspTblClmCount * NspListClmCount) + (NpsSpaceClmCount * (NpsSpaceClmCount - 1))
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(NspFirstRow, Clm(0)), _
                          Cells(NspFirstRow + NspNumRows - 1, Tmp))
    ' read all of the list into an array
    ArrIn = Rng.Value

    ' define a single list column array
    ReDim ArrOut(1 To NspNumRows * NspListClmCount, 1 To NspTblClmCount)

    ' transfer the data to a single list column
    For L = 1 To NspListClmCount
        For R = 1 To NspNumRows
            Rout = (L - 1) * NspNumRows + R
            For C = 1 To NspTblClmCount
                Cin = Clm(L - 1) + C - 1
                ArrOut(Rout, C) = ArrIn(R, Cin)
            Next C
        Next R
    Next L

    ' ArrIn is cleared and re-purposed to take data from ArrOut
    ReDim ArrIn(1 To UBound(ArrOut), 1 To UBound(ArrOut, 2))
    Rin = 0
    For Rout = 1 To UBound(ArrOut)
        ' skip rows where the first column is blank
        If Len(ArrOut(Rout, 1)) Then
            Rin = Rin + 1
            For C = 1 To UBound(ArrOut, 2)
                ArrIn(Rin, C) = ArrOut(Rout, C)
            Next C
        End If
    Next Rout

    ' assign NspNumRows high sections of ArrIn to ArrOut
    For L = 1 To NspListClmCount
        ReDim ArrOut(1 To NspNumRows, 1 To NspTblClmCount)
        For R = 1 To NspNumRows
            For C = 1 To NspTblClmCount
                ArrOut(R, C) = ArrIn(((L - 1) * NspNumRows) + R, C)
            Next C
        Next R
        Set Rng = Cells(NspFirstRow, Clm(L - 1)).Resize(NspNumRows, NspTblClmCount)
        Rng.Value = ArrOut
    Next L
End Sub
```

I'm afraid this code will make the code you already have obsolete. If the first cell in a row is empty any content in the others will be omitted, just like your own code does.

Please pay attention to the enumeration at the top of the code. It works like a switchboard where you can enter all parameters. You can modify them as you wish. For example my code has `NspNumRows = 10`. Your sheet has 27 data rows per column. You will need to change that number. Just to help you find your way:-

1. The "AnchorColumn" is the first sheet column of the first list column. All other columns are counted from there. It need not be column A. You could leave column A blank and anchor your list in Column B (=2).
2. "TableColumns" are the columns that repeat in each "ListColumn". You can have more than 4 or fewer.
3. A "ListColumn" consists of several "TableColumns". You can have more than 2.
4. "SpaceColumns" are blank sheet columns inserted between "ListColumns".
5. `NspFirstRow` specifies the first data row. Above it are captions or other data which this program doesn't touch on. You could reserve the first 10 rows for something else and start your list in row 11.

By setting these 6 enumerations you can create lists of 2 or more List Columns, anywhere on the worksheets, with any number of data rows. Not all of this has been tested exhaustively. When you delete a row anywhere (in fact only the first cell of that row) the list is rewritten to move the blank row to the bottom of the last list column.